# Mask creation using numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, mask

I have this function for creating a mask (array of booleans) and I would like to be much faster.

```
def get_validity_1(ts, times):
    validity = numpy.zeros(len(ts))
    indexes = []
    for start, end in times:
        index_start = numpy.argmax(ts >= start)
        index_end = numpy.argmax(ts >= end)
        indexes.append([index_start, index_end])
    for start, end in indexes:
        validity[start:end] = 1
    return validity
res_1 = get_validity_1(numpy.linspace(0, 1, 100000000), numpy.array([[0.01, 0.1], [0.5, 0.8]]))
```

The asking in this question is how to make it using numpy.where condition. I have tried this:

```
def get_validity_2(ts, times):
    return numpy.where(numpy.logical_or([t1<ts.all()<t2 for t1, t2 in times]))
```

but python raise:

```
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

Here some input assertions:

- ts[n-1] < ts[n]
- times[n][0] < times[n][1]
- times[n-1][1] < times[n][0]

Here is a script as input:

```
import time, numpy

def get_validity_1(ts, times):
    validity = numpy.zeros(len(ts))
    indexes = []
    for start, end in times:
        index_start = numpy.argmax(ts >= start)
        index_end = numpy.argmax(ts >= end)
        indexes.append([index_start, index_end])
    for start, end in indexes:
        validity[start:end] = 1
    return validity
    
def get_validity_2(ts, times):
    return numpy.where(numpy.logical_or([t1<ts.all()<t2 for t1, t2 in times]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 100000000
    ts = numpy.linspace(0, 1, n)
    
    times = numpy.array([[0.01, 0.1], [0.5, 0.8]])
    
    t0 = time.time()
    res_1 = get_validity_1(ts, times)
    t_1 = time.time() - t0
    
    t0 = time.time()
    res_2 = get_validity_2(ts, times)
    t_2 = time.time() - t0
    
    print("t_1: " + str(t_1))
    print("t_2: " + str(t_2))
    
    assert res_1 == res_2
    assert t_1 > t_2
```

Does anyone know how to complete the function 'get_validity_2' and pass the assertions?
Or just a function of a package to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `numpy.where(numpy.logical_or(*[t1<ts.all()<t2 for t1, t2 in times]))`.  Your [mre] should include examples of ts and times. Seems everything but those variables and `get_validity_2` is not relavant to the question.

Comment: `numpy.where(numpy.logical_or(*[t1<ts.all()<t2 for t1, t2 in times]))` return `(array([], dtype=int64),)`
In the end script there is an example with ts and times

Comment: Ahh.I thought you were trying to solve the `ValueError`.

Comment: `np.where` just finds the truth values in its argument.  It's logical or that's making the boolean array.

Comment: I try to have the same results AND be faster. I know that is could be possible using numpy.where

Comment: Does `get_validity_1` work?

Comment: yes it works fine but is is long!

Comment: I don't think you understand what `np.where` does.  Actually with just one argument, you are using `np.nonzero`  I'm not sure you have read its docs.

Comment: You are right, it returns indexs insteed of masks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.logical_or(*[np.logical_and(t1<ts, ts<t2) for t1, t2 in times])
```

if you want a 1-liner like you were trying to achieve. However that's still inefficient because you are comparing large arrays in O(N).

Since ts is sorted, here's a faster way to find the start/end index in O(log(N)) using binary search:

```py
def get_validity_3(ts, times):
    validity = numpy.zeros(len(ts))
    for start, end in times:
        index_start = np.searchsorted(ts, start)
        index_end = np.searchsorted(ts, end)
        validity[index_start:index_end] = 1
    return validity
```

The overall code:

```py
import time, numpy

def get_validity_1(ts, times):
    validity = numpy.zeros(len(ts))
    indexes = []
    for start, end in times:
        index_start = numpy.argmax(ts >= start)
        index_end = numpy.argmax(ts >= end)
        indexes.append([index_start, index_end])
    for start, end in indexes:
        validity[start:end] = 1
    return validity
    
def get_validity_2(ts, times):
    return np.logical_or(*[np.logical_and(t1<ts, ts<t2) for t1, t2 in times])
    
def get_validity_3(ts, times):
    validity = numpy.zeros(len(ts))
    for start, end in times:
        index_start = np.searchsorted(ts, start)
        index_end = np.searchsorted(ts, end)
        validity[index_start:index_end] = 1
    return validity
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 100000000
    ts = numpy.linspace(0, 1, n)
    
    times = numpy.array([[0.01, 0.1], [0.5, 0.8]])
    
    t0 = time.time()
    res_1 = get_validity_1(ts, times)
    t_1 = time.time() - t0
    
    t0 = time.time()
    res_2 = get_validity_2(ts, times)
    t_2 = time.time() - t0
    
    t0 = time.time()
    res_3 = get_validity_3(ts, times)
    t_3 = time.time() - t0
    
    print("t_1: " + str(t_1))
    print("t_2: " + str(t_2))
    print("t_3: " + str(t_3))
    
    assert (res_1 == res_2).all()
    assert (res_1 == res_3).all()
```

Output:

```
t_1: 0.4412200450897217
t_2: 0.3446168899536133
t_3: 0.14597129821777344
```